# COUNTA Query/Filter based on 2 values

Tags: google-sheets

I wish to use the "contains" within a query/filter, but can't get it to work.

Please review the spreadsheet and add in your formula.

formula:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(query(A:B,"Select B where B contains 'Canon' and A contains 'Amateur'")))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ns6N_W-V8TsaTYGIAw14GuCO8K-g7D-MYJCdgoMZSzE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **E2** cell, drag to the right and then drag down:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY($A:$B, 
 "select B 
  where B contains '"&E$1&"' 
    and A contains '"&$D2&"'")))
```

[image: 0]